# What is the correct color gamut to use for Instagram posts?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have been generating some colored drawings and imported them into Adobe Illustrator. The final intent is to export a .PNG to post on Instagram. Regarding colors, I am not sure if should ignore or not the 'out of web color warning'. Could someone clarify to me exactly what goes into 'web' category?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about web safe colours? Web safe colours are obsolete today, and were used back when computers had 8bit graphics, in the 1990s. The modern standard for for photographic images on the web is RGB colour, with an sRGB colour profile.  PNGs also support Indexed colour, but you probably don't want that either, unless it's for a simple web graphic.

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks, good to know. Why is this still present in the latest illustrator build then?? So confusing.

Comment: @ShynnSup programmers dont want to pull the rug under customers. So they dont want to remove features from under users out of respect to users workflow. There is a list of some 20 software I nolonger use because they removed a feature that was seldom used but critical to my workflow. I can never truly trust a company that does this without warning. Its fine if they tell me that feature XX will be depricated in future versions then i can adapt.

Comment: @joojaa I understand that, but, it is not all the same. Billy Kerr just said that web safe colors are totally obsolete today. Meaning, no one is using this in their workflow.

Comment: @ShynnSup correction nobody in for web at least in western world. Does not mean somebody is not doing this for other purposes. It was never even back in 90's something I used. But our friends embedded device designers still use it...